# Population-level prediction from bam {mgcv}

Tags: r, prediction, mixed-models, mgcv

Using `bam`, I made a logistic mixed model with the following form:

```
PresAbs ~ s(Var 1) + s(Var 2) + ... + s(Var n) + s(RandomVar, bs = "re")
```

The `RandomVar` is a factor and I am not interested in the predictions for each of its level. How can I obtain population-level prediction, comparable to [`predict.lme`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/nlme/html/predict.lme.html)?

Comment: Predictions based only on the fixed effects "estimates" comparable to what is available with lme models. e.g. https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/nlme/html/predict.lme.html

Answer (score 1):

One way is just exclude the random effect spline from the predictions.

Using the example from `?gam.models`

```
library("mgcv")
dat <- gamSim(1,n=400,scale=2) ## simulate 4 term additive truth
## Now add some random effects to the simulation. Response is 
## grouped into one of 20 groups by `fac' and each groups has a
## random effect added....
fac <- as.factor(sample(1:20,400,replace=TRUE))
dat$X <- model.matrix(~fac-1)
b <- rnorm(20)*.5
dat$y <- dat$y + dat$X%*%b

m1 <- gam(y ~ s(fac,bs="re")+s(x0)+s(x1)+s(x2)+s(x3),data=dat,method="ML")
```

we want to exclude the term `s(fac)` as it is written in the output from

```
summary(m1)
```

For the observed data, population effects are

```
predict(m1, exclude = 's(fac)')
```

but you can supply `newdata` to generate predictions for other combinations of the covariates.